# Ошибка типа данных. Python+Selenium

Tags: python, строки, циклы, selenium-webdriver, типы-данных

Мой тест проверяет значение в таблице Xpath, но я не могу понять, как организовать цикл, для прогона всех Xpath.

```
def test_search002(self):
    driver = self.driver
    self.ls1 = driver.find_element_by_name("frm_fnd_accno_lst[account_no]")
    self.ls1.clear()
    #self.subscriber_type = driver.find_element_by_id("frm_fnd_accno_lst_acctype_id")
    exp_options = [u"выбрать", u"Физическое лицо", u"Юридическое лицо"]
    act_options = [ ]
    select_subr_type = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("frm_fnd_accno_lst_acctype_id"))
    self.assertEqual(3, len(select_subr_type.options))
    for option in select_subr_type.options:
        act_options.append(option.text)
    self.assertEqual(exp_options, act_options)
    self.assertEqual(u"выбрать", select_subr_type.first_selected_option.text)
    select_subr_type.select_by_visible_text(u"Физическое лицо")
    #self.assertEqual(u"Физическое лицо",)
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("yw0")
    search_button.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    Table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='accountGrv0']/table/tbody")
```

Сама ошибка начинается где-то здесь, на этапе проверки элемента

```
    a = str(114659) #кол-во записей для перебора
    k = 1
    k1 = str(int())
    while a > k:
        k = k + 1
        k1 = str(k)
        for rcgrid_even in Table.find_elements_by_xpath(wait.until("// *[ @ id = 'accountGrv0'] / table / tbody / tr[" + k1 + "]")):
            self.assertTrue("ФЛ", wait.until(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/tr[" + k1 + "]/td[5]")))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите текст вопроса на русский язык или задайте его здесь — **http://stackoverflow.com/**. Спасибо.

Comment: Вряд ли _весь_ ваш код имеет отношение к проблеме - попробуйте изолировать проблемный участок и привести [минимальный самодостаточный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - может быть проблема сама отпадет на этом этапе.

Comment: Не уверен что это ваша ошибка но вот здесь будет ошибка while a > k т.к. тип а str a k int. Какая версия python используется? Если 3 то вроде как точно должна возникать TypeError.